# Angular input binding in structural directive

Tags: angular

I cannot find a way to bind multiple inputs in my structural directive:

view

```
   <div *requiredAccessRight requiredA="[EnumA.A]" requiredB="[EnumB.A]">
```

directive

```
   @Directive({
        // tslint:disable-next-line: directive-selector
        selector: '[requiredAccessRight]',
    })
          export class RequiredAccessRightDirective implements OnInit {
                @Input() requiredA: EnumA[];
                @Input() requiredB: EnumB[];
...
           }
```

during `ngOnInit()` both `Inputs()` will end up `undefined`

Comment: Do you wish to pass multiple values?

Comment: What dou yo mean by that? both requiredA and requiredB take an array of values

Comment: I mean do you want  to pass both the enums?

Comment: Yes thats the whole point of the issue here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inputs of directive follows naming convention as follows:

> Directive input name = directiveSelector + identifier (first character capital)

So in order to create `requiredA` and `requiredB` as inputs you need to have `requiredAccessRightRequiredA` and `requiredAccessRightRequiredB`.

After creating these inputs while using the directive, you always need to pass one value as directive name value.

e.g. in `requiredAccessRight` directive you must have `requiredAccessRight` as input (this is mandatory).

While using the directive, first value will always be without any iedntifier which will be assigned to directive name value. After that by using `;` as separator you can pass other custom inputs.

**Directive**

```js
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[requiredAccessRight]'
})
export class DirectiveDirective {

  private _requiredAccessRight: any;
  private _requiredAccessRightRequiredA: any;
  private _requiredAccessRightRequiredB: any;

  @Input() set requiredAccessRight(value: any[]) {
    this._requiredAccessRight = value;
    console.log(this._requiredAccessRight)
  }

  @Input() set requiredAccessRightRequiredA(enumA) {
    this._requiredAccessRightRequiredA = enumA;
    console.log(this._requiredAccessRightRequiredA);
  }

  @Input() set requiredAccessRightRequiredB(enumB) {
    this._requiredAccessRightRequiredB = enumB;
    console.log(this._requiredAccessRightRequiredB);
  }

  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private vcr: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

**Usage in HTML template**

As first value is mandatory you can pass your value from component in place of `''` or `[]`, I am just using placeholder here.

```html
<button *requiredAccessRight="'';requiredA: [enumA]; requiredB: [enumB]">click</button>
<!-- or -->
<button *requiredAccessRight="[];requiredA: [enumA]; requiredB: [enumB]">click</button>
<!-- or -->
<button *requiredAccessRight="let i;requiredA: [enumA]; requiredB: [enumB]">click</button>
```

Comment: okay so I do have to provide any value for this Input 'requiredAccessRight' even though I only need the 2 other inputs? this kind of smells to me..

Comment: Yes. Actually thats how internally it works. If you see this structural directive after evaluation it will generate `[requiredAccessRight]=""` which will require some value.

Comment: Thanks. Very useful. I was struggling with passing inputs to my custom "if" directive. 

Comment: @yBother You can actually pass the values directly in the main input `requiredAccessRight`, as an object or an array. For example, using `*requiredAccessRight="{a: [enumA], b: [enumB]}"` in your template and updating a little your `RequiredAccessRightDirective.requiredAccessRight` setter to handle an object instead of an array,

Comment: Frankly speaking, i not sure why structural directive support of multiple inputs cannot follow that of the attribute directive..  The former seem complicated than the latter.